# Adding php to an nginx/passenger/configuration

Tags: nginx

what is the best way to proceed if i want to install php and serve some php blog, on a VPS server that is already serving ruby on rails pages through passenger and nginx?

I have set up my vps by following

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/28/setup-a-ubuntu-vps-for-hosting-ruby-on-rails-applications-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my personal experience I suggest using PHP-FPM. Depending on your skill level and your distribution you can either compile it, use some external Repository (e.g. PPA), or the version of your distribution.

Search for PHP-FPM to get further informations and/or additionally provide more informations. Most important your distribution and your intention of use: developing or internet presentation. This might influence the reply in terms of "latest version" vs. "distribution version" is good enough and helps to point you into the right direction to fit your needs.